# Notification everyday at specific time not notifying

Tags: java, android

I want to generate notification everyday at 8:00 AM. I have created the code for simple notification but I am not getting the notification following is the code for NotifyService Class

```
    public class NotifyService extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*Notification Related*/
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                        .setContentTitle("Thought")
                        .setContentText("Get Today's Thought");
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        //mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        // Sets an ID for the notification
        int mNotificationId = 001;
        // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Builds the notification and issues it.
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And this is the code written in the MainActivity class `onCreate` method

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotifyService.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,8);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
    calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Don't know where I am getting wrong

Comment: You should be specific about what exactly is the problem. For example, is the alarm is not firing?. Or it is, but the notification isn't?. Did you try a different time interval? Help people help you.

Comment: I think the alarm is not firing because when I added notification without alarm it worked

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

AlarmManager alarmManager;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Button setAlarm= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    setAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 10, myIntent, 0);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        }
    });

 }
 }
```

AlarmReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    context.startService(startIntent);

    Log.e("TRIGGER", "ALARM TRIGGERED");

 }
 }
```

NotificationService

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Intent inn=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            inn, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Test Message")
                    .setContentText("Hi, you have one notification");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
 }

}
```

Add this in your AndroidManifest file

```
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
    <service android:name=".NotificationService"/>
```

Comment: still not getting the desired result. I dont know why you used the 'button' in the MainActivity. So I removed it and addede the code in the onCreate method. Every time I am opening the app I am getting the notification and when I click the notification, then again a new notification pops up. And when the app is closed I should get the notification at 8 AM but I am not getting it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have created a service here. Notifyservice class extends AppCompatActivity. You should extend Service class to make it a service.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for your problem can be found with the following steps

1. Create a service for alarmnotification
2. Create a receiver to start the service of alarmnotification
3. add the receiver and service into manifest.xml too

Follow the steps of given url.

http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/